# Windows Server 2008 R2 takes a looong time to access file shares

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I have two shared drives that travel with me when I log into remote servers.

I find that Windows Serve 2008 R2 hosts have a hard time accessing them quickly. Doing a "p:" (to change to the shared volume) takes a few seconds and any interaction with the drive ("dir") also takes several seconds every time.

Once an interaction has started, everything is as fast as expected.

I think this affects elevated command prompts only.

Does Windows Server 2008 R2 have a problem accessing shares?

How can I fix this, as it is becoming quite annoying?

Answer (score 0):

A few seconds is normal for me when accessing locally connected drives over a RDP sessions, especially when there are lots of object (files/folders) that need to transmit back to the server.  Are you talking 1-2 seconds or more than that?

[image]

Comment: It's several seconds and it doesn't happen on Windows Server 2003 boxen in the same network.

Comment: Hmm, I remember troubleshooting this a while ago.  Something about the security model is different on the 2008+ boxes.  Are you connecting with the "less secure" option set on the server or is it the default?

Comment: What "less secure" option?

Comment: See the picture in the answer above, is it set to less secure or more secure?

Comment: Yes, it is. Incidentally, the several seconds of waiting time also appear when accessing the drive after a minute or two of no activity.

Comment: I dont know that it will help you but I found the more secure option took longer to connect, seems like a lot of authentication handshakes execute in the background, but I dont know that for sure.